# Scaling text in textview below API 26

Tags: android

I am trying to scale text so it fits within the guidelines set in my constraint layout, currently, when the view is horizontal the text view overlaps the button at the bottom of the screen as its too large. android:autoSizeTextType="uniform" fixes this for newer phones API 26 and above but I am not sure how to do this for any API below that.

This is my code as it stands now:

```
android:id="@+id/destinationTextView"
android:layout_width="360dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/T1"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/headingImage"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Just change

## android:autoSizeTextType="uniform";

to

## app:autoSizeTextType="uniform";